# Wrong number saved in database - Yii framework

Tags: php, post, yii, isset

This may sound a little stupid but I need some help.I should save some records in the database as follow by accessing the following link:

```
http://localhost/whatsapp/index.php?r=users/create&mobile=012345678900
```

This is what I have in the controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Users;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
        echo "hello"." hii";
        if(!isset($_POST['number']))
        {
            echo "aho";
            $model->number="012345678900";
            //$model->number=$_POST['number'];
            echo 'bye';
            //$model->attributes=$_POST['Users'];
            if($model->save())
            echo "done";
                return "Doneeee";
        }

    }
```

The data is saved correctly except the column number.Always a certain number is saved as follows:
2147483647

Any dea why this is happening?!

Comment: what is a type of the field inside db ?

Comment: the number is no coincidende, it is 2^31 -1 :) so the possible max integer value

Comment: you should make the field a varchar(12) or sth similar

Answer (score 2):

Sql engine generate this kind of number when data type is not bigint and length of col is less than the length of number you entered.

Answer (score 2):

In your **Users table** change the type of **number to varchar** and set its **length to 15 or 20 or whatever you want.**

Try this query

**ALTER TABLE `users` CHANGE `number` `number` VARCHAR( 15 )**

`Note:-` You are getting this problem because you have set your number field as int type. and the biggest value int type can hold is what you are getting in the database. So changing it to the varchar type will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A number starting with 0 is regarding as the OCTAL representation of the number

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal

What is happening here is that the octal number, when represented as a "normal" or "decimal" number, gets to large, and overflows in the space provided (kind of like the mileage counter in a motor vehicle). Therefore, when the number gets saved, it gets converted into a number, then overflows.

The correct treatment is to regard this as a string, as suggested by @Let me see